# Alert/Warning E-mail Notifications should be sent from inside the application or through a log analyzer?

Tags: email, logging, system, monitoring

Which is "better":

1. Build e-mail notifications for important events (critical problems and stuff) into my application (a socket server).
2. Build/use a log analyzer to look into each line of the application log checking for some conditions and firing up a script to send emails.

If the second is "better", which tools can I use to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use **[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)**, which includes an [SmtpAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender.html).

It comes with many different appenders so you can very easily configure it to ie. dump all info messages to file, warnings and errors to database and send an email notification for errors only.

You can change the configuration without any changes to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly write my own email notification systems. It's actually useful to learn how to do this, in addition you could write part of your app to check the log as well and do the "best of both worlds" by doing immediately email notification of major events (of which you can use an email notification model of code that you can reuse multiple times, which is the end result of any project right? :) i.e. to write code that can be reused in other realms of your project).

The short version: Both. Just my suggestion.

Comment: Apart from learning a bunch of classes from `System.Net` namespace, what is the point in reinventing the wheel? Instead of wasting time on writing something that has been already written (and probably better) you can invest it in developing the actual software that the users need...

Comment: There isn't much to learn with regards to the MailMessage object. You're also not "reinventing the wheel" if you are customizing the error checking and alerting software to your needs. When you introduce others' code into your own it can result in unknown variables which I tend to like to avoid which is why I gave the suggestion I did. Should we have more programmers out there that don't understand the code that they're using and are just using it arbitrarily because it's readily available? I don't think we should. Perhaps you feel differently.

Comment: I do feel differently - in my opinion the whole point of software development is to minimize duplication and encourage reuse. That's why I use multiple third-party libraries and NuGet packages. I don't want to write my own DBMS just because MS SQL was written by someone else, and I definitely don't want to understand MS SQL server code - I'm more than happy to treat it as a black box ;-)

Comment: That's understandable; however, I not only write software but also maintain our SQL servers. As such it's not much of a hassle to me. We can only give our suggestions/answers from our own perspectives, right? :) I still encourage all software developers to learn as much as they can. We can all benefit from it in the end. btw, I was referring to incorporating other peoples' code into your own (using others' libraries which are unnecessary), not utilizing other people's completed projects (such as a SQL server).

It's really not that much code to write a simple email script with error check. :)